# In SQL Server 2005, how can you lock a specific row against both reads and writes?

Tags: sql-server-2005, locking

I know it's probably a little unusual to lock a row against being read from, but it is kind of relevant in this case.  For a row-level lock in SQL Server 2005, how can you lock a row for both reads and writes?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you concerned about data consistency or data security ??  What you are asking is a little unusual - so understanding your true intention might get you a "better way".  Can you provide more info on what you are trying to avoid (or achieve) by implementing this type of lock.

Comment: @marc_s: that would be nice if it were true; but its not entirely true (blocking writes, yes; blocking reads, no.)  Other sessions can easily workaround exclusive row locks and read row values.

Comment: @marc_s - Even at `readcommitted` an `X` lock on the row doesn't necessarily prevent readers. See [The Case of the Missing Shared Locks](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/11/01/read-committed-shared-locks-and-rollbacks.aspx)

Comment: Whatever reason you have for wanting to "block reads" against a row, it's going to turn out that exclusive row locks and/or exclusive page locks are not the best solution to the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @MartinSmith: interesting article link - thanks! Wasn't aware of that optimization for "skipping" unnecessary shared locks - definitely most interesting to know!

Comment: Guys, I don't always have a choice about how to go about doing something, even if there are other ways.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed as not being a real question.  I understand that the nature of the question is unusual, and that a lot of people feel that there are better ways to approach problems this could be applied to.  I'm looking into other ways.  However this is still a very real, complete question.  I want to know if there is some way to tell SQL Server 2005 to block other threads or processes from reading from or writing to a row, and if so, how it can be done.  I'm going to ask that it please be re-opened.

Comment: I would explain why this is being done, if it weren't for the fact that it would just take an excessively long time to really explain.  I don't see a way that the problem can be summarized very well, unfortunately.  There is another work-around that I'm looking into, but I am also needing to look into possibly doing it this way.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, it can't be done.

You can make a "best shot" effort at preventing reads against a row (at the expense of a considerable negative impact to concurrency) with a page lock.

```
SELECT ... WITH (PAGLOK,XLOCK)
```

If you can obtain an exclusive lock on a page, reads from that page from other sessions will be effectively blocked.  But NOTE: even with an exclusive lock obtained on a page in the clustered index, a reader will still not be prevented from reading row values from an unclustered index. So you still aren't really preventing all reads.

An exclusive row lock (rather than a table or page lock) is basically useless for blocking readers, since sessions and queries can easily workaround exclusive row locks. (Sessions can workaround locks with transaction isolation level, and queries can workaround them using `WITH (NOLOCK)` hints.)

SQL Server locking is a fairly involved subject, I'm not going to attempt to delve into here.

The REAL question (which RThomas highlights in his comment, is figuring out why you would need to prevent reads of a row. Whatever the reason, it's likely going to turn out that obtaining exclusive row (or page) locks is not the best (or right) solution to the problem you are attempting to solve.